# How to remove %07 from url in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, url

This is the url I build in the code logic.

```
redirect_url = "%s?first_variable=%s&second_variable=%s"%(response_url,first_value,second_value)
```

The response URL is built using the following code

```
response_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('workshop:ccavenue_payment_response'))
```

output of this response_url is 
http://localhost:8000/workshop/ccavenue/payment-response/

This is the output URL(redirect url)

http://localhost:8000/workshop/ccavenue/payment-response/%07%07%07%07%07%07%07?first_variable=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&second_variable=encrypted_data

How can I remove %07 from my url ?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: This only occurs when I encrypt the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking after?

```
payload = {'first_variable': first_value, 'second_variable': second_value}
r = requests.get(response_url, params=payload)
```

try with `print(r.url)`